# Voicecall recording using MediaRecorder giving java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-mediarecorder, android-audiomanager

I am trying to record the voice using MediaRecorder when a call comes in and goes out from a phone. I have implemented a BroadcastReceiver to know the states, when the state goes to OFF-HOOK, it starts recording and stops the recording when it enters the IDLE state.

I am using the below code for the recording and saving file to SDCARD

```
private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_3GP = ".3gp";
private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_MP4 = ".mp4";
private static final String AUDIO_RECORDER_FOLDER = "AudioRecorder";
private static boolean recordStarted;
private MediaRecorder recorder;
private int currentFormat = 1;
private int output_formats[] = { MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4,
MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP };
private String file_exts[] = { AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_MP4,
        AUDIO_RECORDER_FILE_EXT_3GP };

**When the state change to OFFHOOK**
 audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
                audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
                recorder = new MediaRecorder();
                //recorder.setMaxDuration(12000);
                recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                recorder.setOutputFormat(output_formats[currentFormat]);
                //recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                recorder.setOutputFile(getFilename());
                recorder.setOnErrorListener(errorListener);
                recorder.setOnInfoListener(infoListener);

                try {
                    recorder.prepare();
                    recorder.start();
                    recordStarted = true;
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                     Log.e("REDORDING :: ",e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("REDORDING :: ",e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
**when the state change to IDLE**
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(false);
            try{
                if (recordStarted) {
                    recorder.stop();
                    recorder.reset();
                    recorder.release();
                    recorder = null;
                    recordStarted = false;
                }
            }catch(RuntimeException stopException){

            }
```

Code sometimes works well but sometimes does not. It gives:

> Unable to start receiver com.afixi.callmanagement.IncomingCallInterceptor: java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed

When the code works it sometimes give indifferent result as well like, sometimes, if the call is of 1:13 , the sound recorded is of 44 seconds.
I have tried using VOICE_CALL instead of MIC, it does the same as well.

Answer (score 0):

Broadcast receiver has specific time of execution

> Once you return from onReceive(), the BroadcastReceiver is no longer
>   active, and its hosting process is only as important as any other
>   application components that are running in it. This is especially
>   important because if that process was only hosting the
>   BroadcastReceiver (a common case for applications that the user has
>   never or not recently interacted with), then upon returning from
>   onReceive() the system will consider its process to be empty and
>   aggressively kill it so that resources are available for other more
>   important processes.

you will need to start a service when you detect incoming and outgoing call fom broadcast receiver and the in service detect phone state and start recording

```
public class TestService extends Service {

public class CustomPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

private static final String TAG = "CustomPhoneStateListener";



@Override
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String phonenumber){


switch(state){
case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
Log.d(TAG, "CALL_STATE_RINGING");
break;


case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
Log.d(TAG, "CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK");

break;


case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
Log.d(TAG, "CALL_STATE_IDLE");
break;

} //switch close
}
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
Log.d("service", "destroy");
super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
final String terminate = intent.getStringExtra("terminate");
TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); //TelephonyManager object
CustomPhoneStateListener customPhoneListener = new CustomPhoneStateListener();
telephony.listen(customPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
if(terminate != null) {
stopSelf();
}
return START_STICKY;
}

}
```

Comment: However it is recording in most of the cases. I can understand the concern, you want to say that I will loose the reference to the Media Recorder object once the state change however, it is not happening. Shall I give it a try using the object as static type?

Comment: no dont use static object for media recorder ,as i have said in my ans try your recording code in service and it will work

Comment: Check my edit it has a sample code to check call state in service

Comment: in offhook write your start recording code and in idle state write stop recording code every thing else will work fine

Comment: and from the boadcast receiver start the service is it the write approach?

Comment: However if I will do that different instance of service will be created with each call from broadcastreceiver?

Comment: not necessary if you give proper condition before starting the service then i dont think there should be any problem

Comment: in the interim I tried your code and called the service from the broadcast receiver, however it is not recording the voice neither turning on the speaker phone from the service. There is no error either? I will see to it. Could you please elaborate about the proper condition you were talking?